# Purpose of "very efficient factories for elements" in p0083

Tags: c++, c++17

[Proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r3.pdf) 
shows weird use of map API:

> This makes possible  things like  very efficient factories  for
>   elements

```
auto new_record()
{
  table_type table;
  table.emplace(...); // Create a record with some parameters.
  return table.extract(table.begin());
}
table.insert(new_record());
```

Assuming record is movable(so returning it from function is not very expensive) is there a point to this code?

Comment: Not all movable things are cheap to move?

Answer (score 2):

It's just an example showing how to create an element and return it without copying (or moving), it's not meant to be production code doing something real.

If you can't see the point of the example, imagine that `table` is not a local variable but some global that might already contain some values:

```
table_type table;
auto insert_record_and_take_first(const Foo& foo, const Bar& bar, const Baz& baz)
{

  table.emplace(foo, bar, baz); // Create a record with some parameters.
  return table.extract(table.begin()); // Remove first 
}
table.insert(insert_record_and_take_first());
```

This wouldn't be possible if the record type is not movable. Even if it's movable it might still be more efficient to do it this way.

> Assuming record is movable (so returning it from function is not very expensive) is there a point to this code?

Is a `pair<const X, Y>` movable? How do you move from a const key?

How do you move from a `std::set` element, when you can only get const iterators to the elements?

Comment: Except the OP is asking about insert.  Replace `insert` with `emplace` and provide a pair with non-const types and, if the elements are efficiently movable, there isn't an advantage over the code the OP posted.  Extracting is a different use case.

Comment: @Yakk, `emplace(key, val)` would be even better than `emplace(pair_with_nonconst_key)`. Maybe the OP should have asked that question if that's what he meant :)